# cardinality problem concerning inclusion of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if $A\subseteq B$ then $A\le B$ , i,e if A is a subset of B then A is less than or equinumerous with B
How to do that? 
IF A is a subset of B then every element in A is an element in B, so A cannot have more elements than B has right?

Answer (score 3):

If $A\subseteq B$ then you have the inclusion mapping $i\colon A\longrightarrow B$ which sends $a\in A$ to itself ($i(a):=a$), seen as an element of $B$. Such a function is trivially injective and then $A\leq B$.

Comment: oh right, I have not thought about that. I have a question if now $A\subseteq B \subseteq C \subseteq D$ and $A\approx D$ how to show that $B\approx C$. For $A\subseteq B$ and $C\subseteq D$ I can apply exactly the same argument as you did right as we have inclusions. How do I then deduce that $B\approx C$?

Comment: Apply this http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder_Theorem/Lemma as follows: $A\subseteq B\subseteq D$ with $A\approx D$ means you have a bijection $f\colon D\rightarrow A$ and then you have an injection $D\rightarrow B$ (the same $f$ regarded as a function with codomain $B$). By that lemma you get ($B:=T$ and $C:=S$ if you want to stick to wiki's notations) $B\approx D$. Similarly you get $C\approx D$ and then $B\approx C$ by transitivity of equinumerosity.

Comment: Pardon, I clearly meant B=:T and D=:S in the previous comment between parentheses.

Comment: I am still thinking about what you have written (I am not really getting it....)  In my book Schröder-Bernstein thm is stated in the following way: If $A\le B$ and $B\le A$ then $A\approx B$ How do you conclude that there exists injection $f:D\to B$, shouldn't this be the other way around, i.e injection $f: B\to D$ as $B\subseteq D$?

Comment: If you can use S-B theorem, it's even simpler. You have an injection $f'\colon B\rightarrow D$ because $B\subseteq D$. But you know that $A\approx D$, i.e $D\approx A$ since equinumerousity is symmetric. This means you have a bijection $f\colon D\rightarrow A$. Now $A\subseteq B$ so you have an injection $i\colon A\rightarrow B$; the composition $i\circ f\colon D\rightarrow B$ is injective because both $f$ and $i$ are. Hence you have $B\leq D$ and $D\leq B$ so that $B\approx D$ by S-B. Ask again if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for you guidance, it really helped me. Could you check if the last step is correct? what is left is to show that $B\approx C$ and I run it as follows: $B\subseteq C$ then $\exists g:B\to C$ injective map, and since $D\approx B$ then $\exists T:D\to B$ is bijective and then $g\circ T:D\to C$ injective thus $D\le C$ but $C\le D$ thus $C\approx D$ but if both $B\approx D$ and $C\approx D$ then $B\approx C$ is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is.

Comment: thanks a lot! /Heidi

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of $A\le B$, in this context, is "there exists an injective function $f:A\to B$". Since $A\subseteq B$, one such injective function would be $f:A\to B$, f(a)=a. This proves that $A\le B$.